# Highlight changing data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a recycler view that has Market, so the asynctask filling and refreshing is being called every 3 seconds. What I want is if a certain column's value change in the recycler I want it to be highlighted for a fraction of a second, how to do so knowing that we can't override the notifyDataSetChanged method? It's not feasible to keep track of old array list and compare every item in it to the items of the new one, so please if you have a valuable solution provide me with it.

Comment: [`DiffUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.html) will help you to understand which items have been changed.

Comment: is there a sample or something please?

Comment: [Here's](https://medium.com/@nullthemall/diffutil-is-a-must-797502bc1149) a nice one.

Comment: wasn't able to apply it, it dispatches the changes to the adapted which fills the enw data, what i want is to highlight these new data

Answer (score 0):

Solved it

```
            //<editor-fold desc="highlighting section">
            OnlineOrder oldOrder = oldAllOrders.get(position);
            OnlineOrder newOrder = newAllOrders.get(position);

            if (oldOrder.getId() == newOrder.getId()){
                //compare here
                //holder.tvPortfolioItem.setTextColor(newOrder.getPortfolioNumber().equals(oldOrder.getPortfolioNumber()) ? Color.BLACK : Color.RED);
                //holder.tvPriceItem.setTextColor(newOrder.getPrice() == oldOrder.getPrice() ? Color.BLACK : Color.RED);
                //holder.tvDateTimeItem.setTextColor(newOrder.getOrderDateTime().equals(oldOrder.getOrderDateTime()) ? Color.BLACK : Color.RED);

                if (!newOrder.getPortfolioNumber().equals(oldOrder.getPortfolioNumber())){

                    int colorFrom = Color.RED ;
                    int colorTo = Color.BLACK ;
                    ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
                    colorAnimation.setDuration(2000); // milliseconds
                    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                            holder.tvPortfolioItem.setTextColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                        }

                    });
                    colorAnimation.start();
                }

                if (newOrder.getPrice() != oldOrder.getPrice()){

                    int colorFrom = Color.RED ;
                    int colorTo = Color.BLACK ;
                    ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
                    colorAnimation.setDuration(2000); // milliseconds
                    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                            holder.tvPriceItem.setTextColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                        }

                    });
                    colorAnimation.start();
                }


                if (!newOrder.getOrderDateTime().equals(oldOrder.getOrderDateTime())){

                    int colorFrom = Color.RED ;
                    int colorTo = Color.BLACK ;
                    ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);
                    colorAnimation.setDuration(2000); // milliseconds
                    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                            holder.tvDateTimeItem.setTextColor((int) animator.getAnimatedValue());
                        }

                    });
                    colorAnimation.start();
                }
            }
            //</editor-fold>
```